# Real Analysis question dealing with Intermediate Value Theorem. Or is there another way to do it?

Tags: real-analysis

The function $g: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, is continuous, $g(1)>0$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$$

Show that for every $y$ between $0$ and $g(1)$ the function takes on a value in $(\ y,\  g(1)\ )$

Comment: are you asking whether to use the IVT or how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Given $0 < y < g(1)$, choose $x_{0}>1$ so that $g(x_{0}) < y$ (this is always possible since $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$). Then by the IVT, since $g(1) > y > g(x_{0})$, for every $u \in (y,g(1))$ there is an $x_{1} \in (1,x_{0})$ such that $g(x_{1}) = u$, as desired.